# Duplicate Record Set not showing all results

Tags: duplicate-management

I have create a duplicate rule and matching rules, both active and deployed. They are showing as Alert & Report but the first few dupes I Saved appeared in the Duplicate Record Set but now it seems to have stopped working. Any ideas?